# (partial) HTTP Request isn't recognized by C# HTTP Server

Tags: c#, http-post, httprequest, httplistener, grapevine

In my visual studio 13 console application, I receive following byte stream on a TCP-Socket(receiving from a embedded device):

```
POST /setup HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 6
Content-Type: application/setup+tlv8

TLV8-data
```

Although it seem to be a valid http request, none of my following attempts have successful been recognize it as a http request: (on regular HTTP Requests they work perfectly)

- .NET HttpListener class (does not even inform me that any request has been invoked)
- Grapevine (same thing, with any routes given on POST or GET) https://github.com/scottoffen/Grapevine
- Alchemy (OnConnect method has been invoked, but in the according UserContext i was just seeing request path: / . Similar to this reported issue: https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/Alchemy-Websockets/issues/70

So far, I'm actually only interested in the requested **path** from the POST or GET as well as the attached **content** (tlv formatted) from the body.

Am I wrong in configuring? such as: I need to tell the proper content-type ?
Is there any way to get rid of writing a own simple text parser ?

Code sample in case of **grapevine**:

```
private void init()
    {
        s = new PairServer();
        s.Host = "172.28.22.78"; 
        s.Port = "52025"; 
        s.Start();
   }
```

providing following server class:

```
public class PairServer : RestServer
    {
        [RestRoute(Method = HttpMethod.POST, PathInfo = @"^/setup")]
        [RestRoute(Method = HttpMethod.GET, PathInfo = @"^/setup")]
        public void PairSetup(HttpListenerContext context)
        {
            // will not reach here
        }

        [RestRoute(Method = HttpMethod.POST)]
        public void AnyRoute(HttpListenerContext context)
        {
           // Not even here
        }
```

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Although it seem to be a valid http request

No, that's not a valid HTTP request. A valid HTTP request, as the [`specification`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23) states, must include a `Host` request header:

> A client MUST include a Host header field in all HTTP/1.1 request
>   messages . If the requested URI does not include an Internet host name
>   for the service being requested, then the Host header field MUST be
>   given with an empty value. An HTTP/1.1 proxy MUST ensure that any
>   request message it forwards does contain an appropriate Host header
>   field that identifies the service being requested by the proxy. All
>   Internet-based HTTP/1.1 servers MUST respond with a 400 (Bad Request)
>   status code to any HTTP/1.1 request message which lacks a Host header
>   field.

So make sure that your client is following the specification:

```
POST /setup HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Length: 6
Content-Type: application/setup+tlv8

TLV8-data
```

Comment: What if I cannot change the http request? So the request always lacks the host header ? Nevermind, your answer explains why regular methods doesn't work.

Comment: @Darin-Dimitrov is correct. Grapevine listens on a protocol/host/port combination using HttpListener, and if your request isn't directed at a specific host (even an IP address should suffice), then it won't ever pick up the request.